# WCF Custom Validator

Tags: wcf, customvalidator

While setting up a CustomValidator I'm getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Ringo.Authentication' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Ringo.Utilities;


namespace Ringo.Authentication
{
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string Username, string Password)
    {
        Accounts account = new Accounts();

        if (account.CheckUserAccount(Username, Password))
        {
            return;
        }

        throw new SecurityTokenException("Accout is Invalid");
    }
}
}


      <serviceCredentials >
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Ringo.Authentication.CustomUserNameValidator, Ringo.Authentication"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```

Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: With issues like these, you should look at [the official WCF sample for something similar to what you are trying to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/user-name-password-validator) and compare your config & code to the working sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Following:

```
<serviceCredentials >
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Ringo.Authentication.CustomUserNameValidator, **Ringo.Authentication**"/>
  </serviceCredentials>
```

Should Be:

```
      <serviceCredentials >
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"  customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Ringo.Authentication.CustomUserNameValidator, **Ringo**"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```